# Add or Read Version Number to the SQL Stored-Procedures or Functions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, version

I need to a version number in the SQL **StoredProcedures** and **Functions** to know what version is using now and necessary to update that or not ?

After searching the Internet I found the table `sys.objects` from the master database. 
`sys.objects` can be fetch SQL elements information like this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.objects
WHERE  TYPE         = 'P'  -- StoredProcedures
       OR  TYPE     = 'FN' -- Functions
       OR  TYPE     = 'U'  -- Usert Tabels
```

Result:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦══════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════╗
║ name ║ object_id ║ schema_id ║ type ║ type_desc ║ create_date ║ modify_date ║ ... ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩══════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════╝
```

But still I could not find a field with the name **Version** or **MetaData** for SQL stored procedures or functions to store some thing like version in that!

## My Questions is:

How do know what version number of **StoresProcedures** or **Functions** is in use? 
And if exist this property, how to change it ?

Or if it's not exist (`Version` field) then can I change `sys.objects` data programmatically ? because I try to change that and seen this error:

> Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

Comment: Hey, why does the version number of the procedure or function matter?

Comment: I have many client by some servers, when I update one SP or FN codes so written that `drop` and `create` scripts within .NET codes and when a client by new script running, first check the SP version on the server to know need to update SP's or not ! and etc...

Comment: Just to clarify - you have 1 code base and many databases that are the same (just with different data)?

Comment: @EdElliott I have many client (.NET app) and Database for that clients (Maybe 1 Server per 10 clients) but does not access to my client servers directly. 

I can to update servers SP or Functions just through clients .NET app. So I wrote all SP and Functions `Drop` and `Recreate` Scripts. 

Now when one client application's updated in the first time that is it running, first of all works check the my SPs or Functions on the itself Server's and if that version is older that self script versions, then update it by drop an recreating ...! 

I hope to presented all information about this question.

Comment: cool, I would go with extended properties - you could use the DacFX api to so a compare / sync of your source code with the database but if you don't control the database you could throw away some of their changes (if they can make changes)

Comment: Late to the game, but if there are potential version conflicts, why not include a version number in the name of the SP or F. If it exists, fine. If it does not, update or add a new piece with the missing version.

Comment: @PepitoSh that's the true answer but in best practice, third-party apps which use this StoredProcedure or Function don't know any version of that and call it by name without version, So update the database hasn't been needed to update application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can update the system catalog, but it's very dirty and I won't suggest it anyway.

Another idea could be just to add a comment over each procedure/function.

A more dynamical way can be a to add a `DDL Trigger` which will count the versions automatically.

Or if you just restrict every procedure/function in a database to have a version, you may have a `DDL Trigger`, which will parse the code for the version number. Afterwards it will log this in a version table. If the version isn't present, you rollback the change and avoid a change. The same can be handled if the version for the specific procedure already exists.

But anyway, these solutions need to be build and may have some (small) side-effects. Depending on their nature of design. But in your case you probably want to have multiple versions of a procedure and behave differently on the call of each one. In this case the comment variant may be the easiest and efficient one for your use-case.

You can also use the [extended Properties](http://www.apexsql.com/help/apexsqldoc/html/Step-by-Step_Guide/Extended_Properties/Managing_Extended_Properties.htm) which need to be set. Maybe this will be a solution you want to live. But this won't avoid duplicate version numbers as described in the `DDL Trigger`.

Another way, if you just want to version your code, can be the usage of GIT + SSDT.

Comment: I think the extended method property method is the proper way to attach a version number to each object.  It would be best to assign the version on the system that is the source of truth, and source controlled to provide the version history.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions. But I have one question, If I want to backup my database and restore that on another systems then this extended properties data are exist on other system or not ? in other words, extended property stored on Master or myDB ?

Comment: The properties are stored in the db itself not in the master db. Which mean you can backup and restore it where ever you want. You can also query the extended properties using `sys.extended_properties` in your db.